# Не могу разобрать смысл задания

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте! Вот часть задания (os - обьект ostream, s - обьект string)

```
Написать функтор Store, который записывает строковую информацию в 
файл. Конструктор Store должен указывать объект ifstream, а  
перегруженная функция operator () (const string &) должна указывать строку,  
подлежащую записи. Приемлемый подход состоит в записи в файл сначала размера 
строки, а затем — ее содержимого. Например, если len содержит размер  
строки, можно было бы использовать следующие операторы:

os.write((char *)&len, sizeof(std::size_t)); // сохранить длину 
os.write(s.data(), len); // сохранить символы

Член data () возвращает указатель на массив, который содержит символы 
строки. Он подобен члену c_str(), за исключением того, что последний  
добавляет нулевой символ.
```

Для чего нужны эти две строки?

Comment: >Для чего нужны эти две строки?

Очевидно, для записи в файл сначала длины строки, потом самой строки. Вам же тут всё побуквенно объяснено, что конкретно из этого непонятно?

Comment: то есть в файле будет написано, например, 4abcd, или выделится 4 свободных символа, которые будут заменены слово abcd?

проще говоря, зачем нужна первая строка?

Comment: Первая строчка делает ровно то, что в ней написано: записывает в файл значение переменной `len`.

Comment: Я проводил тест, компилировал программу, и первая строка записывает в файл несколько непонятных символов вместо длины строки.

Comment: Непонятных **вам**, потому что так записывается двоичное представление числа, а не текстовое (не путать с текстовым представлением числа в двоичной системе счисления). В общем, вам бы взять учебники, да наверстать материал, который прогуляли...